# Set the thumb position of the browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a site that combines anchored scrolling with the normal scrolling, and so I've decided to have a part with a hidden scrollbar, and past a certain point have it be revealed. While I've managed to do this, the thumb of the scrollbar is not in the very top, as I'd like to, since of course the user has scrolled down.

Although, I know for certain this is possible as seen [here](http://lorenzwoehr.com%20here), but checking out the javascript & css I don't really see how he's doing it.

Thus I've come down to 2 options, one being hiding the scrollbar altogether and replacing it with a custom-made one, and the other one being having the anchored scroll section in fact be right over the normal scroll section and simply move away through some javascript animation (Might be hard to understand what I mean, but basically if you check out the link above it'll make more sense).

Hope anyone can help give some insight on the matter!

Comment: I found the script file he is using to achieve that: http://lorenzwoehr.com/assets/scripts/slide.js

Answer (score 0):

When the page scrolls the body changes from

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to

```
overflow: auto;
```

`overflow: hidden` is the reason the scrollbar is hidden. You can use Javascript to detect scroll, or page position, and then make this style change to the body. There are also many scrolling plugins that will help you achieve this or similar.

Comment: I do already know how to make the scrollbar hidden, but the thing is, if you check on his site, when you have scrolled down (or pressed the arrow) the scrollbar thumb is displayed in the very top.

Comment: Yes, he's changing the css on the body once you have scrolled down. Overflow: hidden is removed. And you can see the scrollbar again.

Comment: This is the plugin he's using: http://www.slidesjs.com ... there are a lot of similar plugins.

Comment: So would that make the thumb of the scrollbar appear on the very top after scrolling down, or it would just hide and show the scrollbar?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is. This plugin might be more suitable: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/. There are options for displaying and hiding the scrollbar. You could hide it for the first section of your site, and then display it for the remaining sections. There are a lot of options, the documentation is very good and the developer is active here on this site. There might be better alternatives but it seems a reasonable place to start.